# How do I add classnames to a React.ReactNode prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Consider this parent element. How can I pass React.ReactNodes as props (`icon`) in this example, but still have control over what class names are rendered?

```
interface Props {
  url: string;
  slug: string;
  icon: React.ReactNode;
  color: string;
}

export default function SocialButton({ url, slug, icon, color }: Props) {
  const openLink = (url: string) => window.open(url, "_blank", "noreferrer");

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => openLink(url)}
      className={`group/${slug} rounded p-2 hover:bg-${color}-600 transition-all`}
    >
      {icon}
      // Should be something like, however not possible because the actual component is dynamic of course...
      // <BsLinkedin className={`h-6 w-6 fill-stone-500 dark:fill-stone-200 group-hover/${slug}:fill-stone-50 transition-all`} />
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so using [Children](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children), but React recommends not doing so as it leads to fragile code.

---

Instead of passing `icon` to `SocialButton`, pass a function that returns `icon`.

Here pass to `renderIcon` the `calssName` you need.

```
interface Props {
  url: string;
  slug: string;
  renderIcon: (className:string) => React.ReactNode;
  color: string;
}


export default function SocialButton({ url, slug, renderIcon, color }: Props) {
  const openLink = (url: string) => window.open(url, "_blank", "noreferrer");

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => openLink(url)}
      className={`group/${slug} rounded p-2 hover:bg-${color}-600 transition-all`}
    >
      {renderIcon('icon-class')}
    </button>
  );
}
```

`renderIcon` returns the icon you need to use in  `SocialButton`.

```
const Parent = () => {
  return <SocialButton url={'https://google.com'} slug={'/icon'} renderIcon={(className) => {
     return <span className={className}>Icon</span>

  }} color={'blue'} />
}
```

#### Reference

https://react.dev/reference/react/Children#calling-a-render-prop-to-customize-rendering

Comment: Can you explain me how React knows that the param that you are passing is for the prop 'className' of the element that you will render? I'm surprized because I use this approach and it works, but I don't understand why this works!